# apache2.distrib:1 duplicate log entry for /var/log/apache2/access.log

Tags: apt, server, apache2

I have an Apache bug.

(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1945311 - Ubuntu 18 version 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.18 on my Plesk Ubuntu server).

I found a workaround here:

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407366133906-Website-suddenly-started-to-show-500-error-AH10292-Invalid-proxy-UDS-filename?page=2#comments

And execute (before it was officially fixed by Apache):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt install apache2
```

After that I get daily new messages with:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: apache2.distrib:1 duplicate log entry for /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Do you have tips for me?

Was the workaround a safe method to add a new repository I don't know the creator?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 18  Adding anything to your system from an trusted source is always a gamble.

Comment: Looks like you've encountered a bug. You may want to let the developer(s) behind the `ondrej/apache2` repo know about the issue so that they can resolve the issue in a future update 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for)

Answer (score 1):

There are two files in `/etc/logrotate.d`: `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` and `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2.distrib`. The latter is the renamed and diverted logrotate file originally distributed by the apache2 package, while the former is the one shipped/created by Plesk (it seems). The diversion, created with `dpkg-divert`, seems to have been created by Plesk too.

Both files contain rules for the same set of log files, which leads to the logrotate warning message, which is then announced by cron via mail.

The solution is very simple: comment out the whole entry in `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2.distrib`.

So this is not a bug in the apache2 package. Instead, the Plesk packages could improve handling this diversion to not leave two files in `/etc/logrotate.d` referencing the same log files.